# Setting layout for rails forem gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, forum

I am using the Rails forem gem and I would like to use a different layout for some of the forum actions. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

If it's for some *particular* actions inside a controller then I would use a *decorator* for that. Simply put this file in `app/decorators/forem/forums_controller_decorator.rb`:

```
Forem::ForumsController.class_eval do
  layout "my_special_layout", :only => :show
end
```

If you want it for all the actions in a specific controller then you should use an intializer:

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Forem::ForumsController.layout "my_special_layout"
end
```

Comment: I got the initializer to work but the decorator didn't work. I tried just creating the file you mentioned and nothing happened. I tried installing the draper gem first and that also did nothing. Is there something else I am supposed to do?

Comment: you may have to require the file somewhere, [like we do in spree](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/auth/lib/spree/auth/engine.rb#L11-21). The file is not automatically loaded.

Comment: Looks complicated. I think I will just stick to using the initializer. Thanks.